# Are the buffer of input and output different in C?

Tags: c, assembly, buffer

Are the buffer of a C input and output different ? I am trying to implement buffering emulation in assembly and trying to do it as the C one does. I have so far implemented buffering system in my fgets function, however, I am not sure how I should implement it in case of fputs function. If the "buffer" are same, then it does make sense to implement a global variable which will contain the file descriptor last used so that in the case of a "fputs, fgets, fputs" operation, I can use the last file descriptor to flush out the buffer before reading in case of fgets. But this method also seems very costy, as I have to flush out the buffer every time regardless of the fact that I called a fputs function before. Or should I use two buffer for inputting and outputting ?

Answer (score 1):

> Or should I use two buffer for inputting and outputting ?

Suggest using one buffer per file handle; that should cover the common use cases — rather than buffering based on i/o direction.

Comment: won't that be costy ? One 1024 byte for each file? Or is it normal ?

Comment: @MostofaHimal: That's what C stdio does.  Most programs only have a few open files at a time, and a couple 4k or 8kiB IO buffers aren't a lot of total RAM on modern PCs, even added up across multiple processes.  A bidirectional stream might even need one buffer for each direction, although I'm not sure exactly what C stdio normally does for `fopen(file, "rw")`.